# Searching two tables in one function in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to link two tables in DynamoDB for an Amazon Alexa skill. I am using two tables one is named 'yesno' and the other 'fixtures'. The fixtures table has a list of 22 names in each record and these names are in the 'yesno' table along with the column 'goals'. Here you can see the tables in more detail. Name Table:
[image: name table]

Fixtures Table:
[image]

[image]

As you can see there are names that link the two databases together. I use the team1 column to search the fixtures table and use the name column to search the name table. Here is my code for searching:

```
 function readDynamoItem(params2, callback) {
        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        AWS.config.update({region: AWSregion});

        var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
        const names = new Array();



        console.log('reading item from DynamoDB table');

        dynamodb.scan(params2, function (err, data){
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else{
                console.log(data); // successful response
                //tried to put a automatic loop for the long bit of code after this but didnt work so anyone with insight on this too would be helpful
                /*for(var i = 1; i <= 11; i++){
                    var str = "T1S";
                    var pos = i.toString();
                    pos = str.concat(pos);
                    names[i] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].pos);
                }
                for(var j = 1; j <= 11; j++){
                    str = "T2S";
                    pos = j.toString();
                    pos = str.concat(pos);
                    names[(j+11)] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].pos);
                }
                */

                names[1] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T1S1);
                names[2] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T1S2);
                names[3] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T1S3);
                names[4] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T1S4);
                names[5] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T1S5);
                names[6] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T1S6);
                names[7] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T1S7);
                names[8] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T1S8);
                names[9] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T1S9);
                names[10] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T1S10);
                names[11] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T1S11);
                names[12] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T2S1);
                names[13] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T2S2);
                names[14] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T2S3);
                names[15] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T2S4);
                names[16] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T2S5);
                names[17] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T2S6);
                names[18] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T2S7);
                names[19] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T2S8);
                names[20] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T2S9);
                names[21] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T2S10);
                names[22] = jsonToString(data.Items[0].T2S11);
            }
        });

        var goals =  new Array();
        //for loop to be used later when expanding
        //for(var i = 1; i <= 22; i++){
            var params = {
                TableName: 'yesno',
                FilterExpression: 'name = :value',
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {':value': {"S": names[2]}}
            };
            dynamodb.scan(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else{
                    console.log(data); // successful response
                    var temp = jsonToString(data.Items[0].goals);
                    goals[1] = temp; 
                }    
            callback(goals[1]);
            });
        //}
    }
function jsonToString(str){
    str = JSON.stringify(str);
    str = str.replace('{\"S\":\"', '');
    str = str.replace('\"}', '');
    return str;
}
```

I am trying to use the goals array to print each persons goals off but right now it won't even print one persons and instead will print an undefined object of some sort. I'm guessing it just can't search the names table using the names array. The main bit of code I am having a problem with is when searching the yesno table as you can see in this code:

```
 var goals =  new Array();
        //for loop to be used later when expanding
        //for(var i = 1; i <= 22; i++){
            var params = {
                TableName: 'yesno',
                FilterExpression: 'name = :value',
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {':value': {"S": names[2]}}
            };
            dynamodb.scan(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else{
                    console.log(data); // successful response
                    var temp = jsonToString(data.Items[0].goals);
                    goals[1] = temp; 
                }    
            callback(goals[1]);
            });
        //}
```

I know for sure there is nothing wrong with the implementation but here it is just in case it is helpful:

```
const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.response.speak('welcome to magic answers.  ask me a yes or no question.').listen('try again');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },


    'MyIntent': function () {
        var MyQuestion = this.event.request.intent.slots.MyQuestion.value;
        console.log('MyQuestion : ' + MyQuestion);


        const params2 = {
            TableName: 'Fixtures',
            FilterExpression: 'team1 = :value',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {':value': {"S": MyQuestion.toLowerCase()}}
        };
        //const params3 = {
        //    TableName: 'Fixtures',
        //    FilterExpression: 'team2 = :value',
        //    ExpressionAttributeValues: {':value': {"S": MyQuestion.toLowerCase()}}
        //};

        readDynamoItem(params2, myResult=>{
            var say = MyQuestion;
            say = myResult;

            say = 'The top scorer for ' + MyQuestion + ' is ' + myResult;
            this.response.speak(say).listen('try again');
            this.emit(':responseReady');


        });

    },
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak('ask me a yes or no question.').listen('try again');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak('Goodbye!');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak('Goodbye!');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    }
}
```

;

Comment: Can you narrow-down your question to a specific bit of code? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry I've edited the post to show the exact code I'm having a problem with but i thought it necessary to leave the rest in as it's hard to understand the function without knowledge of the database and the implementation of the function.

Comment: Console the value of names[2] and check for extra spaces in it, do manual search whether the data is available in yesno table.  If it didnt works update your question with console.log response data of DB Scan for Fixtures and yesno table.

Comment: Hi yes I've had a look at the console logs now and i can see that I'm getting this message:                                                              
message: 'Invalid FilterExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: name', Any ideas??